# Weird rails migration behaviour - migration is successful but still data doesn't populate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration, postgresql-9.1

The below migration file runs successfully without any error and even column gets created but weirdly the data doesn't gets updated.

If I run the code in rails console (ignoring the create column) it works super good. Any Explanation:

```
class AddSubjectListToTestType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :test_types, :subject_list, :integer, array:true, default: []

    type_hash = {
        "NEET" => ["Physics" , "Chemistry", "Botany", "Zoology"],
        "JEE" => ["Physics", "Chemistry", "Mathematics"],
        "CET" => ["Physics", "Chemistry", "Mathematics"]
    }
    TestType.all.each do |test_type|
        type_hash[test_type.name].each do |subject|
            test_type.subject_list << Subject.find_by_name(subject).id
        end
        test_type.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It iterates through all `test_types`, so my first question is how many of these you have in your database?
BTW it isn't best practice to make migrations coupled with models. Models can change, migrations aren't supposed to.

Comment: I have only three records in test types and all three have the names as listed in keys of  question_count_per_subject.

Answer (score 0):

first thing to check is your development.log file, scroll all the way to the bottom for the latest entries.

here's how to add a column
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column

take all of the other stuff out and move to your model.

Comment: I am able to add column already. Now how do I generate default dataset if I move the code to model.

Comment: oh ok, didn't realize you were trying to use it to create some type of dataset.  Use db/seeds.rb instead.  So basically create the column and then populate the db/seeds.rb file then run rails db:seed (rails 5.x) or rake db:seed if you're on rails 4.  This will allow you to populate your database with any initial data that you want in there.

Comment: here's a link with some more info on using db/seeds.rb to populate your database.  http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html